# How do I check if a guessed character is in a string in this code?

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do is if the user guesses the correct letter in the correct spot, it will output the letter in green. If the user guesses the letter that's in the answer, but that's in the wrong spot, it will output in red. And if the user guesses a letter that's not in the answer it will output in black. I'm struggling to figure out how to make it so that it will check if the letter is in the code but not the right place.

```
<script>
var secret = 'OPIMNC';
function init(){
    var button = document.getElementById('startButton');
    button.onclick = myButtonClick;
}
function myButtonClick(){
    var userTry = document.getElementById('userGuess').value;
    var ul = document.getElementById('guessList');
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    for (var i=0; i < secret.length; i++) {
        var found = false;
        if ((userTry.charAt(i))===(secret.charAt(i))) {
            li.innerHTML += userTry.charAt(i).fontcolor('green');
            found = true;
        }

        //if character is in the code but in the wrong place, output the font in red
        else if ???? {
            for (var j=0; j < secret.length; j++) {
            ??????????????
            }
            found = true;
            li.innerHTML += userTry.charAt(i).fontcolor('red');


        else if (found===false) {
            li.innerHTML += userTry.charAt(i).fontcolor('black');
        }
    }
    ul.appendChild(li);
}

window.onload = init;
</script>
```

Comment: Does the user input a word or a letter ?

Comment: They input 6 letters

Comment: Okok I am creating a snippet

Comment: I added a working snippet :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var secret = 'ABCDEF';

function init() {
  var button = document.getElementById('startButton');
  button.onclick = myButtonClick;
}

function myButtonClick() {
  var userTry = document.getElementById('userGuess').value;
  if(userTry.length !== 6){
    document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "I need 6 characters !";
    return;
  }
  document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "";
  
  var ul = document.getElementById('guessList');
  ul.innerHTML = ""; //Clear list
  
  for (var i = 0; i < secret.length; i++) {
    var color;
    if (userTry.charAt(i) === secret.charAt(i)) {
      //Correct index
      color = 'geen'
    } else if (secret.indexOf(userTry.charAt(i)) !== -1) {
      //Present but wrong index
      color = 'red';
    } else {
      //Not present
      color = 'black';
    }
    
    //Add letters to list with correct colors
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = userTry.charAt(i).fontcolor(color);
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
}
window.onload = init;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="userGuess" maxlength="6"/>
<button type="submit" id="startButton">Start</button>

<p style="color: red;" id="error"></p>

<ul id="guessList">
  
</ul>
```

Comment: Yep I did it just says it doesn't show since I have less than 15 reputation

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the [string.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method?

```
if(secret.indexOf('[CHAR or STRING]') >= 0) {
// Character or string is within secret string
} else {
// Character or string is NOT within secret string : index == -1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, so i hope this change in code will solve the problem...

```js
<script>
var secret = 'ABCDEF';
function init(){
    var button = document.getElementById('startButton');
    button.onclick = myButtonClick;
}
function myButtonClick(){
    //alert('Button clicked');
    var userTry = document.getElementById('userGuess').value;
    var ul = document.getElementById('guessList');
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    for (var i=0; i < secret.length; i++) {
        var found = false;
        if ((userTry.charAt(i))===(secret.charAt(i))) {
            //if secret code and guess are a match, display letter in green
            li.innerHTML += userTry.charAt(i).fontcolor('green');
            found = true;
        }

        //~~~~~~~~~~~~CHANGE HERE~~~~~~~~~~~~
        else {
            for (var j=0; j < secret.length; j++) {
              if ((userTry.charAt(i))===(secret.charAt(j))) {
                found = true;
              }
            }
          
            if (found===true) {
              li.innerHTML += userTry.charAt(i).fontcolor('red');
            }
            else {
              //need to show user character is totally wrong
              li.innerHTML += userTry.charAt(i).fontcolor('black');
            }
        }
        //~~~~~~~~~~~~CHANGE END~~~~~~~~~~~~
    }
    ul.appendChild(li);
    alert(userTry);
}

window.onload = init;
</script>
```

best luck for you!

Comment: The double loop is not necessary

Comment: + you can insert a break after `found=true` in the second loop